# Horizontal List, with flexible height

Tags: css, cross-browser, horizontallist

Id like to make a horizontal list, with image contents. The image size should follow the height of the ul, which reacts to the height of the container.

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nLcrW/

```
#container{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    height: 70%;    
    background: cyan;
}

.HList{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.HList-Item{
    display: inline-block;   
    height: 100%;
}
.HList img{
     height: 100%;
}
```

Try to scale the container window in the fiddle. The images will overlapp when scaled up, and stretch when scaled down in Chrome and Firefox. It works perfectly in Safari.

Is there an other way to make this working, or a workaround for these browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an update of your [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/nLcrW/1/).

Just adjust the size of the HList-Item, make the image 100% of that.

You can now play with the styling, add whitespace, remove it, embed the images in an anchor, etc.

CSS

```
#container{
    top: 15%;
    height: 70%;    
    background: cyan;
}
.HList{
    list-style: none;
}
.HList-Item{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 5%;
    width: 18%;
}
.HList img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```